# Why does this function return integer series?

Tags: pine-script

Why does this function return integer series?

call it as
 d = find_bar(time,20)

when I use lowest(close,d)
I get an error that d is integer series.

```
find_bar(time_array,bar) =>
        counter = bar
        o = 0
        what = time_array[0]
        if bar == 0
            0
        else
            for i = 1 to 100000
                if time_array[i]-what[0]!=0
                    counter:= counter - 1
                    what:= time_array[i]
                    if counter == 0
                        o := i
                        break
            o[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here.

1) `[]` operator in pine-script returns a value of series type. So, `o[0]` is a series type, hence your function returns a value of series type.

2) `:=` operator is assigning a new value to a variable. This makes it a series type. The reason is, with every new bar, your script will be re-executed and `:=` will add a new value to the variable's (in your case "o") history. So it becomes a series type (a variable that has historical values). You can access those historical values with the `[]` operator.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid returning a series type in this case?

Comment: @Aftershock Unfortunately, no.